# Horizontal scroll a UICollectionView all the way to the right/last cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've got a UICollectionView containing 4 cells. The last of the 4 cells is halfway off the screen. How do I programmatically scroll all the way to the right so that the first of the 4 cells is located halfway off screen?

I've tried:

```
if (self.activeSection == .WISHES){
     cell.neighbourhoodHeaderCollectionView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(CGFloat.max, 0), animated: false)
}
```

How it is now:

[image]

How it needs to be:

[image]

Comment: Try using `scrollToItem` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618046-scrolltoitem)) instead of `setContentOffset`

Comment: I've tried. Doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this...

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0/*top*/, 5/*left*/, 0/*bottom*/, 5/*right*/);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything for my view

Comment: I got it working but I needed to add some delay to it. Code was firing before the view was done loading.